# Trustworthy USB and HDMI Manufacturers?

Tags: usb, hdmi, manufacturing

Undoubtedly, we've all encountered the frustrating scenario of surfing through the sea of replica / knockoff products on Amazon and similar marketplaces; in my personal experience, particularly for USB and HDMI cables and equipment.

Further muddying the waters are, as there have always been, paid reviews, sponsorships, and so on.

Perhaps it's my naivety, but "professional" grade products, as in marketed to professionals rather than regular consumers, don't have the same (*volume of, at least*) spam everywhere.

Are there any manufacturers of USB and HDMI cables that target "professional" (*or at least non-Amazon consumer*) audiences, with a positive reputation preceding them of verifiable standards compliance, accurate marketing / advertising / labelling, and so on?

Household names like Samsung and Sony seem to come up short on variety, I'm guessing due to their diversified product catalog.

So, tl;dr — what USB and HDMI cable manufacturers are trustworthy, have accurately labeled standard compliant and certified products, and ideally have a non-miniscule catalog? Price is "not an object", so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

For things like this I either buy directly from a major supermarket - where you may not find the highest quality or largest selection of all, but you are fairly certain to get what it says on the pack.

Some higher-end things I will buy - again over the counter - from a reputable hi-fi/TV chain [personally I use Richer Sounds, but I think they're UK only].  This tends to only be for high-end AV stuff, 8k-ready HDMI, that sort of thing. You do tend to pay quite a premium for this stuff as it suffers from a bit of *'this gold-plating is oxygen free & all points in the same direction'* kind of *'audiophool'* marketing;)
You could find similar & cheaper from a large retail park white goods/audio/TV/computers nation-wide retailer; Currys, etc [again idk if they're international].

All of these because I'll be pretty sure I'm getting what it says on the label & I can take it back if I don't like it.

If what I need is more esoteric, or needs to work with quite specific equipment - Macs rather than generic PCs - then Belkin or Anker are known-good. I quite often buy from the Apple Store online or retail for this type of thing. If it's for Apple & Apple make one of their own, then I will buy it because then it is 100% guaranteed to work for what I need. Again, you pay extra for that.

Anything else, or if I need odd connectors at each end, something a little more esoteric, or longer than normal lengths, I will go to [StarTech](https://www.startech.com/) online [they have physical presence in many countries, chose top left on their home page.] Their gear is reliable & direct. Their catalogue is colossal.
Their descriptions are accurate. They try hard to accurately differentiate between active & passive converters etc rather than blind you with amazon-esque marketing speak.
They stand by their stuff & accept returns for any reason. I once had to send back some extra-long DVI cables because it turned out only one of four GPUS I had in different computers was powerful enough to push clean data that far. They exchanged for shorter & refunded the difference, no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, we (in Canada) don't have brick-and-mortar Richer Sounds or Currys. Nevertheless, as with the other answer I replied to, Star Tech is a vendor I've used in the past, and wasn't disappointed. Belkin I've had mixed experiences with, but Anker I've heard many great things about too.

Answer (score 1):

Star Tech and Cable Matters are good cable suppliers who sell through Amazon, and also have their own web sites, sometimes with more info than is on Amazon and sometimes even better prices.  Just for USB-C cables via Amazon I've also had good experience with Nimaso; they have a 4-pack of cables that's often quite a bargain.  The cables are flexible, can handle the power to charge laptops, and have good strain relief.

Comment: After exhaustive comparison, I'm going with Star Tech and/or Cable Matters and/or Anker. Any opinion of the latter?